# interior.colorindex on VBA-autofilter hidden cell ends function with #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a bizarre problem when using VBA to autofilter. A cell in the top row (O1) contains a reference to a user-defined function to check the color of another cell (F2). If I *manually* autofilter so the referenced cell F2 is hidden, the function works fine. If I have a VBA script performing the EXACT SAME FILTER (I used Macro Record to make sure), it returns a #VALUE! error. Stepping through the code in debug mode, it hits the Interior.ColorIndex line - and silently exits the function (returning #VALUE!) without hitting the next Stop or generating a VBA error.

Cell O1 contains:

```
=stupidFunction()
```

VBA code:

```
Function stupidFunction()
Application.Volatile True
Calculate
Stop
stupidFunction = Range("F2").Interior.ColorIndex
Stop 'VBA autofilter never gets here, manual autofilter does!
End Function


Sub TestFilter()
'
' TestFilter Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$82").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "=*Approval*", Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: do you have the function code in a module or sheet code?

Comment: AFAIK you can't access other cells in a UDF.

Comment: Function is in a module. Function works *perfectly* so long as I don't use VBA-initiated autofilters. While you cannot ALTER any cells (contents, format, colors, etc) in a UDF, you CAN look at the properties of other cells.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the question.

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior, but adding `ActiveSheet.Calculate` immediately after applying the VBA filtering fixes it (as does manually re-triggering the formula)

Comment: Tim, you're quite correct. I've confirmed that ActiveSheet.Calculate fixes it, and that'll work for me. Please put this in as an answer, so I can select/upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm the same behavior, but adding

```
ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

immediately after applying the VBA filtering fixes it (as does manually re-triggering the formula)